# Attempting to read file and save its content to a struct, not working

Tags: c

I have been trying to save **register.txt** contents to my main file and put it into a struct, it works until I try to print the actual struct. Somehow it doesn't go into it, like it does not save as an array, so the print I have written on the last line prints out what is on the **register.txt** file but the code does not save its contents as an array/struct in the main file. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Anvandarnamn 100
#define Register 10
#define antalval 100

typedef struct {
    char Fornamn[Anvandarnamn];
    char Efternamn[Anvandarnamn];
    int alder;
} agare;

typedef struct {
    agare user;
    char marke[Anvandarnamn];
    char typ[Anvandarnamn];
    char reg[6];
} fordon;

void Readfile(fordon bil[]) {
    FILE *txt;
    txt = fopen("Register.txt", "r"); 
    int i;
 
    for (i = 0; i < Register; i++) {
        fscanf(txt, "%s %s %s %s %d %s",
               bil[i].marke, bil[i].typ, bil[i].user.Fornamn,
               bil[i].user.Efternamn, &bil[i].user.alder, bil[i].reg);
    }
    fclose(txt);
}

int main() {
    fordon bil[Register];
    Readfile(bil);
    int raknare = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s\t %s\t %s %s\t %d\t %s \n",
               bil[i].marke, bil[i].typ, bil[i].user.Fornamn,
               bil[i].user.Efternamn, bil[i].user.alder, bil[i].reg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, [your code seems working well](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tSECRCpKsctIXL5u). What are the contents of `Register.txt`, expected output and actual output?

Comment: The file is created with another function, that I decided to not include in this code with a fopen(..."w"); 
The contents on the Register.txt vary, but they are printed out as they are in the last line of code, but as stated earlier they do not go into the struct for some reason.

Comment: Without seeing a sample file or the code where it was created, we can't answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons your code could fail: you should add some error testing.

- test if `fopen()` succeeds and report failures with an explicit message that includes the filename.
- test for `fscanf()` failure and report those.

Here is a modified version of `ReadFile`:

```
// pass the maximum count of records and return actual count
int Readfile(int count, fordon bil[]) {
    FILE *txt;
    int i;

    txt = fopen("Register.txt", "r");
    if (txt == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open Register.txt\n");
        return -1;
    }
 
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // tell fscanf the maximum length of each string field
        if (fscanf(txt, "%99s %99s %99s %99s %d %5s",
                   bil[i].marke, bil[i].typ, bil[i].user.Fornamn,
                   bil[i].user.Efternamn, &bil[i].user.alder, bil[i].reg) != 6) {
            fprintf(stderr, "read failed for record %d\n", i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(txt);
    return i;
}
```